# Multiple related model new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, multi-step

I have a model called `Nonsense` which has_one of `Foo` and `Bar`

In my controller for `Nonsense` I need to create the related entries for `Foo` and `Bar`

The reason I have to create those I that I need to show the links to `Foo` and `Bar` in the `new` action, because of the nature of the application the details for `Nonsense` might not be known until `Foo` and `Bar` have been filled out.

What I'm trying to do in the new action for `Nonsense` is this

```
def new
  @nonsense = Nonsense.new
  @nonsense.bar = Bar.new
  @nonsense.foo = Foo.new
...
```

now the problem I am encountering is that in the `show` view that the path helper will complain about the id for `@nonsense.foo` and `@nonsense.bar` are nil.

In the show view I just do `@nonsense = Nonsense.find(params[:id])` and `nonsense` `accepts_nested_attributes_for :foo, :bar`

Any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Bar.new actually creates an object in the database, so the id is actually still nil. If you want a link to those objects, you will need to save them first.

Can you save them with some default details? I haven't used rails much, but I think you need to be careful to clean those out if you don't end up committing Nonsense. More importantly, I suspect your workflow and/or data model need to be straightened out, but maybe I am just not familiar with more complex rails setups.

Finally, If all these things are dependent and part of your Model logic, then you should probably be creating those objects in the Nonsense model and attaching everything that the controller needs. Otherwise you are letting your Model logic leak into the controller.

To be more explicit (I'm pretty sure this is bad rails form by the way, even if it works):

```
def new
  @nonsense = Nonsense.new

  @nonsense.bar = Bar.new
  @nonsense.bar.any_necessary_attributes = some_value
  @nonsense.bar.save

  @nonsense.foo = Foo.new
  @nonsense.foo.any_necessary_attributes = some_value
  @nonsense.foo.save
...
```

Comment: would I need to `@nonsense.save` or both `Foo` and `Bar`?

Comment: If you are using the restful style controller setups (index, show, new, create, ...) then you shouldn't be saving your new object in the new controller. New just gives you something to work with for example with forms. Create is where you should save your new Nonsense object.

Comment: How would have have a link to a related object on the `new` view before that object is saved?

Comment: If all of this doesn't make sense, I suggest you check out the excellent [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) site. Excellent, free online and worth every minute.

Comment: I meant that you shouldn't save the Nonsense object. If you really need Foo and Bar objects, then create and save those (better to do that all in the model first, but you can do it in the controller).

Comment: i'm thinking it would probably better to have a nested form but with parts of that form collapsed.

Comment: Should I be doing this http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms instead?

Comment: Many questions leading in many directions. I think you need to update the original question with more concrete information about what you are trying to accomplish.